# Удаление вируса из файла

Tags: malware

Добрый день!
Пациент: заряженный пока не известным вирусом компьютер. Жутко тормозит, название файлов и папок не отображается, установка новых файлов не возможно.
Что сделано: Снят и исследован дамп памяти с помощью volatility. Благодаря чему найден зловред в хроме.
Вопрос: Как или чем можно быстро снять образ диска и уже в нем найти хром и дебагером занопать зловредные инструкции, далее редактированный образ закатать обратно. 
PS: Надеюсь я думаю в правильном направлении, потому что просто открыть олю в заряженной системе не представляется возможным, даже в безопасном режиме. Если у вас есть другие идеи буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Практика показывает, что все благие намерения заканчиваются гемороем в несколько дней/недель. Проще ось переставить.

Comment: Если бы можно было во так по-быстрому выяснить, где же зловредные байты у неизвестного вируса, то и антивирусы писал бы каждый программист. Не, анализ чужого кода, да ещё небось и сопротивляющегося анализу — очень непростая штука.

Comment: life cd + антивирус

Comment: Что касается криптозащиты и сопротивляемости реверсу, то читайте внимательно - СНЯТ ДАМП ПАМЯТИ (это означает, что зловред уже загружен в память, соответственно при наличии какой либо защиты он уже распокавался.)

Answer (score 2):

Думаешь действительно в правильно направлении, но то что ты хочешь ближе к фантастике, обычно, чтобы впустую не тратить время, выгоднее по времени и трудозатратам переустановить ось на отформатированный диск.

Если хочешь исследовать, советую снять образ системы, программой типа акрониса, переустановить ОС, установить виртуальную машину, накатить на виртуалку образ, и там уже ловить зловредную программу. Можно запускать в песочнице хром, у некоторых антивирусов она есть, также можно делать снимки реестра до запуска и после и сравнивать их. Посмотри [автозагрузку](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

Comment: Согласен, но это самый легкий путь, просто переставить систему...... Что называется "решение в массы", так только деградация, никакого развития. Live cd и антивирус как запасной вариант, если уже никак. Самое смешное, что я знаю где и с какого адреса начинается зловред, нужно только занопать.... Но похоже это не так просто.